# Sort Values inside a tuple in F#

Tags: sorting, f#, tuples

I have a tuple that stores 3 records in it and I would like to sort the tuple in the following way.

The original tuple is:

```
({X = 5; Y = 1; By = B}, {X = 4; Y = 0; By = B}, {X = 5; Y = 0; By = B})
```

I would like to get:

```
({X = 4; Y = 0; By = B}, {X = 5; Y = 0; By = B}, {X = 5; Y = 1; By = B})
```

I want the tuples to be first sorted by X and then by Y. I'm fairly new to F# and hence I'm struggling with this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tuples are generally not something you would sort, would you be better using a list? Tuples are a way of representing a pair (or more) of items, where as a list is something you would sort.

Comment: @DaveShaw Thanks. I was initially working with lists instead of tuples but didn't want to embrace a list of lists. That's why I created a list of tuples. But as per your suggestion, a list of lists is a better idea and it has solved my problem. If you wish, you can add it as an answer so that I can mark it right.

Comment: Tuples are a light weight data structure, at the moment you have a tuple of records. Converting this to a list of records would be the most idiomatic thing to do. I might be worth having a look at fsharpforfunandprofit.com which explains the different data structures in F#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of records would likely be more correct. If you must have exactly 3 items and you want them to be ordered I would probably at least use a list as a intermediate representation just due to ease of use.

```
let sort (a,b,c) = 
    let l = [a;b;c] |> List.sortBy (fun r -> r.X, r.Y)
    (l.[0], l.[1], l.[2])
```